# Why are moving objects and actors, that have been added to the Gazebo environment, not being detected by Sick LMS Scanner on ClearPath Husky?

Tags: ros, sensors, navigation, gazebo, ros-noetic

I am using ROS Noetic and Gazebo.

https://github.com/JiangweiNEU/actor_collisions is used as the world, but the human walking actor is not being detected by the Husky laser scanner despite `HUSKY_LMS1XX_ENABLED=1`.

I am trying to use https://github.com/kangbeenlee/rrtx_global_planner/tree/main/src as the global planner in the move_base.

Request help with additions to code and commands to be run.

Comment: I've made an attempt to clarify the title by removing the repetition and word re-ordering. Please verify that the clarification is correct.